# Get underlying soap message of wsimport generated ws client

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport

I'm in the following situation:
I use a wsdl file to generate a webservice client with wsimport.
The generated (central) class looks like this:

```
@WebServiceClient(...)
public class FooService extends javax.xml.ws.Service
```

Then I use this class to get a "port"...

```
Foo port = (new FooService()).getHTTPSPort();
```

and then I invoke the webservice...

```
... result = port.foo(...);
```

where `result` then will be the server's response as a java bean (with corresponding getters).

**I want to obtain the underlying soap message of that result.**

So far, I managed to obtain ***a*** soap message with the following approach:
I attach a handler to the port binding handler chain...

```
List<Handler> handlerChainCopy = ((BindingProvider) port).getBinding().getHandlerChain();
handlerChainCopy.add(...);
((BindingProvider) port).getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChainCopy);
```

where my handler looks like this

```
class MyHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
  private final ByteArrayOutputStream myStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  public String getLastMessage(Charset charset){
    return new String(this.myStream.toByteArray(), charset);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context){
    this.myStream.reset();
    try {
      context.getMessage().writeTo(this.myStream);
    } catch (Exception ignored) { }
    return true /*(don't) block processing*/;
  }
  ...
```

(I guess, alternatively I could use setHandlerResolver on my `fooService` object - but that doesn't change my problem, see below.)

**And this all works, *kind of*.**

I am not convinced at all that proceeding like this is *correct*, and I haven't found any documentation that would guarantee correctness.

**My main concern is synchronization between `result = port.foo(...)` and `myHandler.getLastMessage(...)`.**

(Of course, I have "control" over `new FooService()`, but the 
`Foo port = (new FooService()).getHTTPSPort()`
object is dynamically constructed (or obtained!) from the depth of the j2ee server and I have no control whether it is shared between different FooService instances.

**Is there any way to guarantee correctness?**
Or maybe there is a completly different approach? (Of course, I very much would like to use what wsimport / jax-ws is providing, I don't want to manually implement the complete soap message processing and parsing chain. And I don't want to manually adjust the Result class so that it can store the message, either.)

Thanks
Thomas